# What kind of wood is around this fireplace?

Tags: wood, fireplace

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

Could any one tell me what kind of wood that is around the fireplace? Is that just skirting board, or Dado rail or what?  I don't know what to look for.  Judging by the picture the wood is about 70mm wide (it looks about the same as the width of a brick).
I'm just having trouble finding something online that looks like it.

I'm in the UK by the way- I've had a scout around on B&Q and Wickes website...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called Casing and is mainly used around doors and windows.

[image: Case Moulding]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pretty standard door and window trim to me.

Comment: Yes- I just this minute came to the same conclusion- also apparently called "Architrave"!  Cheers!